# How to add frame by using Tui-image-editor

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface

Please help me find a solution to this. I don't know how to add frame by using Tui-image-editor.js

Answer (score 1):

Create an image of a frame and Upload it via **Load Mask Image** then do not click on the **apply image** button, just click on the **Mask** button again. Now you can use or resize it. It is not a perfect solution but helped in my case.